# C, using random and storing them in an array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, random

Just trying to generate 25 random numbers between 60-100 and storing them in an array.  Need some confirmation though.  Is this how it would look?

```
int main () {

int temp[25], i, sum;


srand( (unsigned) time(NULL) );

for (i=0; i <= 25; i++) {

get_value(i);
sum += temp[25];  //Eventually will be added together to find avg

};


}


int get_value(int temp_random) {
    return((rand()%40)+60);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by

- using out-of-range array subscript.
- using value of uninitialized variable `sum` having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate.

The line `sum += temp[25];` should be `sum += temp[i];`,
and the loop condition should be `i < 25` or `i < (int)(sizeof(temp)/sizeof(*temp))` instead of `i <= 25`.

Also `sum` have to be initialized.

Bisides of the *undefined behavior*, your program has following problems:

- What `get_value()` returns is thrown away.
- `get_value()` has unused and seems meaningless arugment `temp_random`.
- Functions are used before they are declared.
- `get_value()` won't return `100` because `rand()%40` will be only numbers between 0 and 39, inclusive.

Also note that the semicolon fter the block that belongs to the `for` loop is not needed. (This is not harmful though)

Your code should be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define GENERATE_NUM 25
#define GENVALUE_MIN 60
#define GENVALUE_MAX 100

int get_value(void);

int main (void) {

    int temp[GENERATE_NUM], i, sum = 0;

    srand( (unsigned) time(NULL) );

    for (i=0; i < GENERATE_NUM; i++) {

        temp[i] = get_value();
        sum += temp[i];  //Eventually will be added together to find avg

    }

    return 0;
}

int get_value(void) {
    return((rand() % (GENVALUE_MAX - GENVALUE_MIN + 1)) + GENVALUE_MIN);

}
```

Comment: Lol thanks guys for helping me with all these mistakes.  I get the concepts, but the syntax is my problem ><

Answer (score 2):

Many issues:

- Your `get_value` taking a param but never used it.
- Your random calculation wasn't correct.
- Your index `i` was wrong because it ran out-of-bound.
- Your `for` loop ended with `;` which was incorrect as well.

Refer to this running code - don't forget `#include<limits.h>`

```
int get_value( int a, int b ); // <-- allow to get a random number in range [a, b]

int main() 
{
    int temp[25], i, sum;
    srand( (unsigned) time(NULL) );
    for (i=0; i < 25; i++) {
        temp[i] = get_value( 60, 100 );
        printf( "tmp[%d] = %d\n", i, temp[i] );
    }
}

int get_value( int a, int b ) {
    return a + rand() % (b + 1 - a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The formula for generating a random number between `a` and `b` is: `rand() % (b-a+1) + a`.
That said, your for-loop should be looking something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    temp[i] = rand() % (100-60+1) + 60;
    sum += temp[i];
}
```

Also, pay attention to what you did in the for-loop condition (`i <= 25`). This would go from 0 (including) to 25 (including), but the last index of your array is `24`.